# Netsuite Advanced PDF item list alternate row color

Tags: pdf, netsuite

I'm trying to make the item rows have alternate background color.

For example the first item line to be white background then second line grey, and so on.

The last line is shipping and not a part of the item list.

[This is my list section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3lqi.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the item index is divisible by two and apply styling conditionally based on that:

```
<tr style="background-color:${(item_index % 2 == 1)?then('#eeeeee;','')}">
```

For example, the above code could be used as a replacement for your `<tr>` tag on line 218 from your screenshot.